# How to solve this double ajax calls issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do 2 ajax function calls when a user clicks a button.

I have

```
$('.test').on('click', function(){

    code.getCode();
        code.getText();
})

code.prototype.getCode=function(){
     var call=//call ajax
     call.callback= function(data){
          //parse return data
    }
}


code.prototype.getText=function(){
     var call=//call ajax
     call.callback= function(data){
          //parse return data
    }
}
```

I can only do 1 ajax call and only 1 ajax call will return data. 
I am not sure how to solve this. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what are you expecting to happen with regard to the 2 AJAX calls?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong...`code.prototype.getCode()=function`??

Comment: @charlietfl, I need to do 2 database searches.

Comment: can you do 2 database searches in one call?

Comment: not explaining sequencing issues enough or not showing enough code. Bothe will fire with edit you made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly, but I think you are looking for a single callback from both the ajax calls..

You should use **[$.when.done](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)**. See below,

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function(a1,  a2){
    /* a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the 
        page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively */
   var jqXHR = a1[2]; /* arguments are [ "success", statusText, jqXHR ] */
   if ( /Whip It/.test(jqXHR.responseText) ) {
      alert("First page has 'Whip It' somewhere.");
   }
});
```

Not sure if you looking for sequencing it or trying to have 1 callback.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have the first ajax call, call the second on success:

```
$('.test').on('click', function(){

var datastr = "your data";

 $.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "url",  
  data: datastr,  
  success: function(successMsg) {                   
          //ajax done
          if (/* not yet complete */) {
            setTimeout(secondAjaxCall(),500);
          } else {
            secondAjaxCall();
         }
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just save each return in the code object (since you are in a different context you have to work around "this"). Then you can use a third function that checks if the data objects are loaded... and start parsing once both are there.

```
$('.test').on('click', function(){
    code.getCode();
    code.getText();
})
code.prototype.getCode=function(){
     var call=//call ajax
     var that = this;
     call.callback= function(data){
          //parse return data
          that.codeData = data;
          parseData();
    }
}
code.prototype.getText=function(){
     var call=//call ajax
     var that = this;
     call.callback= function(data){
          //parse return data
          that.textData = data;
          parseData();
    }
}
function parseData() {
 if(!code.textData || !code.codeData) return;
 ... work with both
}
```